# JavaScript - svg hover won't work after I assign color to the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

In my CSS I have two classes for svg defined

```
.room:hover {
    fill: blue;
}

.room {
    fill: #f4cb42;
    stroke: #000000;
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
```

In my JS things go like this:

```
function highlightRoom(room) {
    var roomName = room['name'].toString();
    var area = document.getElementById("x" + roomName);
    if (area !== null) {
        area.style.fill = "#2bd923";
    }
}
```

But after the room is highlighted the hover functionality won't work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please provide full code so that we can test it ourselves

Comment: Hey, When you say the hover won't work. You mean, it doesn't change color to blue when you hover it. This doesn't mean the hover doesn't work anymore. It may just be the `fill: blue;` that is overriden

Comment: Obviously if you set it in JS, your CSS will be overridden (inline styles are marked highest in CSS, so `style=""` will always take prefernce over `<style>` or `<link>` tags). So you might want to consider adding a class to the element and controlling its styling through CSS. AKA instead of `area.style.fill = "#2bd923";` use `area.className = 'selected';`, and remove the class when done _selecting_. Then use `.room.selected { fill:  "#2bd923"; }` in CSS to control it smoothly and not override any values defined in your CSS itself.

Comment: @somethinghere that totally worked! thanks.